# Listas desplegables dependientes validación de datos Google sheet

Tags: validación, google-hoja-de-cálculo

he estado intentando replicar la función de excel de listas desplegables dependientes
Por ejemplo, tengo filas que completar mediante listas

```
a1 b1
a2 b2
a3 b3
a4 b4
a5 b5
a6 b6
....
infinito
```

donde columna a es una lista desplegable, y columna b es una lista desplegable donde los valores de la lista dependerán de lo seleccionado en la columna A.

En excel es fácil de hacer, mediante asignación de nombres a tablas, y generar validación de datos con lista que dependen de lo seleccionado en la columna A.
He intentado realizarlo pero solo lo logro para cerdas especificas, con la función filter e indirecto.

¿Alguien sabe como realizarlo en google sheet?

Answer (score 0):

Acá encontré una respuesta que realiza lo que necesito:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JJLA1YAvoqQsV6kNYdn6I1o0OGh0k9kadoZEqGZ46fc/edit#gid=482029573

se trata de un app script, con activación al editar.

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).